# The sum of the first n elements of a geometric series within an arithmetic series II

Tags: c, math, series, clion

Task description:

*Calculate the sum of the first n elements of a series s1, s2 = s1 + d1, s3 = s2 + d2, ...
where the differences d1, d2, ... between the elements form a geometric series.
The function receives the first three elements of the series (first, second and third) as well as n values.
The return value of the function is the sum s1 + ... + sn.
The nth element of the geometric series: dn = d1 * q ^ (n-1)*

The first test case:

```
struct {double first; double second; double third; int n; double sum;} testlist[1] = {
            {1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 5, 57.0},
            {1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 5, 11.125}
```

My code is: (with the help of Oli L)

```
double series(double first, double second, double third, int n) {

    if(n <= 0) return 0;
    double d1 = second-first;
    double d2 = third-second;
    double q = d2/d1;
    
    double s[n];
    double d[n];

    double result = q;

    s[0] = first;
    d[0] = d1;
    double sum = s[0];

    for( int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
        
        d[i] = d1*result;
        result*=q;

        s[i] = s[i-1] + d[i-1];
        sum += s[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don’t see any more test cases and I can’t extract the main function either, as I have to upload my code to a strict page that tests it after pasting it into the encrypted frame.

So far, with a little help, I've gotten as far as I can, 4 out of 5 test cases run successfully, but one (which I don't see) isn't good. I would ask for ideas on what the problem might be, what an extreme case I might not have thought, or what the code might look like then.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that I can only try to upload a total of 9 times.

Comment: The issue is likely that your code is too slow, as it is linear. Think about deriving a formula. Start by deriving a formula for s_i.

Comment: Hint: decompose the final sum to something of the form: X(N) * s_1 + Y(N, q) * d_1. You might also find this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence

Comment: A run time of 5 seconds is allowed for each test case, for a total of 25 seconds. However, in each case 0.001s is the runtime in the test program, returning only one of the incorrect results.

Comment: The "first test case" `testlist[1]` has too many initializers.

Comment: One possibility is the test administration code does not allow much leeway for differences in errors due to floating-point round. Another possibility is the failing test case has all s[i] terms identical, so the d[i] terms are all zero, forming a degenerate geometric series 0, 0, 0,… so your code gets a NaN in `d2/d1`.

Comment: Of the 5 test cases, only 4th gives a wrong result. The main function is well over 200 lines, I don't see it, but I know the test cases work reliably.

Comment: @bcseh202: To what are you responding? The fact that only one of the five test cases gives a wrong result does not contradict either the possibility the test administration code does not allow much leeway for differences in floating-point errors or the possibility that one of the test cases has a degenerate geometric series. The latter is easily tested by fixing your code to handle that case.

Comment: I added the appropriate line (at the beginning), but so the 3rd and 4th test cases were already incorrect, not only the 4th. So I think I misunderstood you Eric Postpischil. if(n <= 0 || (third-second)/(second-first) <= 0) return 0;

Comment: If `first`, `second`, and `third` have the same value, then `(third-second)/(second-first) <= 0` will evaluate to false in typical C implementations, because `(third-second)/(second-first)` will evaluate first to `0./0.` and then to a NaN, and comparing a NaN to 0 with `<=` yields false. So that line is not a fix for the degenerate geometric series issue. Also, 0 is not the correct answer when there is a geometric series. There would be `n` terms all with the same value, so the sum would be `first*n`.

Comment: I added the following line 'if(third == second && second == first) return first*n;' and now all of the five cases are passed, so thank you so much Eric! :)

Answer (score 0):

The sequence 0, 0, 0,… is a geometric sequence (it satisfies *d*<sub>*i*</sub> = d<sub>1</sub>•*q*<sup>*i*−1</sup> by using 0 for *q*) that is not handled by the code in the question. For this series of differences, all the *s*<sub>*i*</sub> are equal. Notably, `first`, `second`, and `third` have the same value.

When this occurs, `d1` and `d2` are set to 0 by these lines:

```
double d1 = second-first;
double d2 = third-second;
```

and then `double q = d2/d1;` sets `q` to a NaN (Not a Number, a “value” used in floating-point to indicate there is no suitable real number). This NaN propagates through other calculations, causing the routine to return a NaN.

When the sequence is a sequence of identical terms with zero differences, the sum of *n* terms is `n*first`. So the code in the question can be corrected by handling this case just after the test for `n <= 0`:

```
if (first == second && second == third)
    return n*first;
```